# Unable to make an Image blink getting ) expected error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to make an image blink which is a part of my web part on sharepoint.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn1" onclick="imgbtn1_Click" ImageUrl="~/xxxxx.gif" runat="server" onload="Javascript:return blink();" />

function blink() {
    var e = document.getElementById("imgbtn1");
    e.style.visibility = (e.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    setTimeout("blink();", 500);
}
```

Whenever I try to load the page with the image, i get ) expected error. Is there something wrong with my syntax? please let me know...

Comment: I thought it was because of `onload="Javascript:return blink();"`, but it seems that the `Javascript:` part of it doesn't give an error like I thought it would. I assume it is interpreted as a label or something.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/xruh7/  Please post the generated HTML instead of the server tags (or along with the server tags).  Debug your code and check the stack trace to make sure that `blink()` is really the culprit.  Maybe some other script is causing the issue.

Comment: Oh, you are getting a *Server* error.  (I just tried it)  That would've been useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

Use `OnClientClick` instead of `OnClick`. `OnClick` is for server-side:

I think this should work:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn1" OnClientClick="blink(); return false;" ImageUrl="~/xxxxx.gif" runat="server" />

function blink() {
    var e = document.getElementById("<%=imgbtn1.ClientID%>");
    e.style.visibility = (e.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    setTimeout("blink();", 500);
}
```

Notice how I changed the part where you get a reference to imgBtn. You need to use `<%=imgBtn.ClientID%>`

**EDIT**

Apparently I misunderstood the purpose of your `OnClick`

This should do it then:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn1" OnClick="imgbtn1_Click" ImageUrl="~/xxxxx.gif" runat="server"/>

window.onload=blink;
function blink() {
    var e = document.getElementById("<%=imgbtn1.ClientID%>");
    e.style.visibility = (e.style.visibility == 'visible') ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    setTimeout("blink();", 500);
}
```

If you think doing `window.onload=blink` is a big deal, then do this on `Page_Load`:

```
Page_Load()
{
   imgBtn.Attributes.Add("onload","blink();");
}
```

Comment: `blink()` is intended to be called during `img.onload` (see the `onload` attribute).  That `OnClick="imgbtn1_Click"`, was most likely intended to be a server handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the `OnLoad` attribute of `<asp:ImageButton />` to execute JavaScript because that is used for setting a server-side event handler for the control's `Load` event.  Here's a workaround:

In your server-side `Page_Load` handler:

```cs
imgbtn1.Attributes["onload"] = "blink()";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1038225.aspx/1

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

always use

```
    "<%=id.ClientID%>"
```

when you use getelementbyid in JavaScript if you are combining the asp and JavaScript because asp will change the id at run time so the server element id will be different and the client id which you are expecting will be different.